# Hyper-v Port mirroring

Tags: hyper-v, mirroring

I have traffic flows from switch to physical port on a server in which should mirror the traffic to a virtual switch which is connected to a sensor.

I have tried the following links but the vSwitch seems to not receive traffic from physical port.

[Configure traffic mirroring with a Hyper-V vSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-iot/organizations/traffic-mirroring/configure-mirror-hyper-v#configure-the-switchs-mirroring-mode)

[How to set Hyper-V promiscuous mode for monitoring external traffic](https://cloudbase.it/hyper-v-promiscuous-mode/)

But none of that works for me.

Update: After running a wireshark on the vSwitch it only captures ICMP and DHCP traffic!